# how to get event in an angularjs function

Tags: html, angularjs

In this code event display undefined.

```
<div class="div1" ng-click="displayinfo(event)">
    sadfasf
</div>

$scope.displayinfo = function(event)
{
     alert(event);
}
```

can anyone help.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $event instead of event.
It is little hidden in the docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick

Comment: Although this is the correct answer it should be noted that injecting DOM events to controller functions is often a bad practice as most of the time any DOM manipulation logic should be kept out of controllers and moved to directives instead.

Answer (score 2):

Very close--but it's `$event`.

```
<div class="div1" ng-click="displayinfo($event)">
    sadfasf
</div>

$scope.displayinfo = function(event)
{
     alert(event);
}
```